# launch putty from shell script

Tags: linux, windows, unix, ssh, putty

I have written a shell script that gives user a list of accounts to log-in and when the user selects an account,he/she gets logged into the selected account via ssh.The script is run from master account and has password-less ssh connectivity with all the other accounts in the list(slaves).Instead of ssh connection from the master I would like to `launch another putty session` with slave account details passed as arguments.How can I achieve this ?

One thing that comes to my mind is that if I can write a batch file(my users use windows) that takes account information as arguments.And this batch **script** could be called inside the unix script(is this possible).So unix script will execute the batch file on windows via ssh and in the process it will also pass the parameters(server details) to putty.

Or is there any other better way ?

**Edit**

To ssh from linux machine to windows machine,is it compulsary to host some kind of server(i.e. telnet, ssh, ftp or any other kind of server) on Windows machine ?

Comment: "Batch could be called inside the unix script". What do you mean by this? You can't run unix shell scripts on windows (unless you use something like cygwin), and you'd just use `ssh` instead anyway. Maybe I'm not understanding...

Comment: I still don't get how you call a windows batch file from a unix script... Are you ssh-ing from a *nix box into a Windows box?

Comment: Yes ,to execute the batch file on windows from unix,I will have to ssh to windows and and run this batch file.

Comment: Check out this: http://etherealmind.com/putty-command-line/ for information on running putty from the command line. Also, I'm not totally clear on how you're doing this, but you may be able to set the user credentials to be Windows Variables

Comment: Also: In theory, you should be able to use ssh -t user@host 'C:\pathtoputty\putty.exe'. Using the link above (and escaping characters) you should be able to piece together what I think you mean :)

Comment: >To ssh from linux machine to windows machine,is it compulsary to host some kind of server(i.e. telnet, ssh, ftp or any other kind of server) on Windows machine ?

You obviously would need an sshd server installed on the Windows machine to connect to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going FROM a GNU Linux or UNIX machine you don't need to use putty at all. Just use SSH. The options in the native SSH are way more flexible than running through something less native like PuTTY.

And yes, your destination will require a server in order to "catch" the connection from your source computer. You will also have to make sure that the default port of 22 is open all the way through.

However... From what it sounds like what you're trying to do. I recommend you look into using SSH keys and "launching" SSH through su/sudo. (Instead of the normal user launching su/sudo to get root. The root account can launch ANYTHING under another account.)